# System Testing tool for Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, testing

I want to test my hardware function and find errors.

Is there any System Testing tool available for Arch Linux with GNOME 3.20 ?

On Ubuntu , I was using [Checkbox-qt](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/checkbox-qt/) to test all the Input/Output Devices. I have not tried installing it from the source as I don't know how to do it properly.

So, I am searching for similar tools which would run on or Even Procedure to Install Checkbot-qt from the source with dependencies would be appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What exactly do you want to test? What hardware? What type of stress do you need to apply? You mentioned [checkbox-qt](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/checkbox-qt/) in a comment. Add that to your question and explain what parts of its functionality you are looking for. Have you tried installing it from source?

Comment: I have edited the question :)

Comment: _Phoronix Test Suite_ includes system tests.

Answer (score 1):

As said [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_maintenance#Check_for_errors), you can use `systemctl --failed`

Comment: Nice! :) , but I would like to have a tool like [checkbox-qt](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/checkbox-qt/) (checkbox-qt is available only on Ubuntu) .

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps start with this : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Stress_Test - it looks like a pretty good start. Are you sure that checkbox-qt (never used it) isn't in AUR? If not, why not build it yourself?